# sdk compatibility issues

Tags: android, sdk, compatibility

I am developing an application that is on version 3.2 which consists of a gallery widget for my cover flow.

If I upload the app on google play, will a device running on 3.2 and above (maybe 4) be able to run it? Because in 4.0, the gallery widget has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If I upload the app on google play, will a device running on 3.2 and above (maybe 4) be able to run it?`

YES it will run perfectly, no issues.

`the gallery widget has been deprecated.`

Deprecated means that do not use it any more. Because they provide many other efficient ways to achieve same functionality. But if you use them it will work perfectly.

Comment: But when I tried to run on a 4.0 emulator, it crashes and say I have an java.lang.Outofmemoryerror

Comment: `java.lang.Outofmemoryerror` only comes on `4.0` ? I guess it is due Images.